# Transient OS Code in Single Partition Allocation?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

While going through the slides of a lecture on memory management, I came across this:

> Relocation register value is static during program execution. Hence all of the OS must be present (it might be used). Otherwise, we have to relocate user code/data “on the fly”! In other words, we cannot have transient OS code

I couldn't understand what the above lines meant. I would appreciate if anyone could explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relocation-register scheme provides an effective way to allow the
operating system’s size to change dynamically. This flexibility is desirable in
many situations. For example, the operating system contains code and buffer
space for device drivers.

If a device driver (or other operating-system service) is not commonly used, we do not want to keep the code and data inmemory, as
we might be able to use that space for other purposes. Such code is sometimes
called transient operating-system code; it comes and goes as needed. Thus,
using this code changes the size of the operating system during program
execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. All the logical memory references in user code are mapped to physical address space using Relocation Register value.(Phy.add = Rel.reg_val + log.add).
2. The value of Relocation-Register is set by OS. So it will be unaffected by user processes.
3. A transient code in Operating System means that it is active for just small time (useless for long time like code to check if the processor is deadlocked). So the Relocation-Register Scheme tries to allocate the memory occupied by this transient code to some other process in job Queue of Main Memory.Shrinking or expanding OS process boundary with nearby processes (because of single partition allocation).

By knowing above points, if transient code is present in OS, due to changes in boundaries of processes with OS process, we should be able to relocate user code/data frequently.